# How can I prepare for Apple WWDC 2018 event live broadcast and rebroadcast?

Tags: appletv, developer-program

I expect I will not be able to view the livestream of the WWDC main public keynote event.

Has Apple announced any plans for non-attendee viewing of WWDC keynote and events?

Comment: Even if Apple follows the same schedule where they professionally edit and subtitle the rebroadcast, WWDC is hundreds of events. How it decides to rebroadcast the headline event will likely be different than the ones available only to developers in the app. If that’s a good enough answer, please flag and comment and I’ll check with the other mods if we want to make an exception about future events policy.

Comment: I feel like no one would actually be able to answer the question, as it seems unlikely that Apple did announce any such plans. I think a better question would be related to how long after the event Apple usually uploads their keynote to watch again. Is that a more valid question?

Comment: Asking how long after should be closed as pure speculation. It's a wikipedia article listing how long it happened in the past and begging the question that it will be the same next time.

Answer (score 1):

To prepare for 2018 WWDC I would recommend three things:

1. AppleTV and updating it now for the Live Stream and Rebroadcast of the main presentation in the morning and afternoon of the first day. These keynote events are highly viewed and usually available for on-demand viewing and professionally produced.
2. WWDC app on the App Store is also very good if you are a registered developer as you can watch many of the sessions live and should expect to be able to rebroadcast.
3. Safari web browser is the third best option - in past years -there were not any sort of YouTube or third party browsers.

As to why these three avenues were selected last year is that the sessions under developer NDA require authentication with an AppleID. Also, on a technical level - the streaming used the latest QuickTime codecs for presumable efficiency, quality. Also, there would be marketing synergies of potential value to Apple by using their own technology for a high stakes  / high pressure / high expectations and in demand public event.

Hopefully this helps people prepare for the 2018 remote viewing of the sessions at this year's developer conference.

—-

As a postscript - the WWDC app is showing the live stream on rebroadcast within hours of the main event completing.